# Firebug / Chrome debugger inside 1-line function

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

This question is entirely for my own curiosity. So there are a lot of methods in Angular (and probably other frameworks) that are defined anonymously on one line. For example (taken from angular-route.js):

```
$http.get(templateUrl, {cache: $templateCache}).
    then(function(response) { return response.data; })
```

I want to set a breakpoint inside the promise callback and inspect what's in `response` at that point. For the moment I've just been temporarily hacking at the source, which isn't ideal.

This is an odd request, I know, and I'm almost certain the UI doesn't provide for it. But you never know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you're actually asking for is to be able to format the code, so it's easy to set the breakpoint right at the `return response.data;` statement.

The Chrome DevTools have an option for this:

[image]

as well as the Firefox DevTools:

[image]

In combination with [source maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) it's possible to debug minified code easily.

For Firebug it is also planned for one of the next versions to integrate code pretty-printing and source maps. See [issue 1238](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=1238) and [issue 5765](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5765) there.